# manage.py migrate does not detect changes

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migrate

I have a python project using django restframework. It was initally using an sqlite - database. Now I've changed it to a postgresql. All the data is replaced and the project now uses the postgresql database. It all works fine.

But now I had to change something in my python project. I had to delete some field in a model (called 'product'). So after it I checked my django restframework in my browser and the field was gone. So the field didn't exist anymore for my backend. All fine but when I tried to add a new product I get an error. Because my database still expects me to fill in the deleted field.

**The field is still in my database but it isn't described in the 0001_initial.py**. So I think the makemigrations did its job but the migrate failed?

I already did the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

And also

```
python manage.py makemigrations (changed app)
python manage.py migrate
```

I really don't know the reason. Because the field is deleted in my project and in the initial.py so I thought the migrate would detect it and change the database.

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are a cumulative record. The initial migration describes the state of your database when you initially created it. Subsequent changes are described by further migration files, each of which takes your database to the state at the time that migration was created.

So when you run `makemigrations`, a migration 0002 will be created which will include the code to remove your field.